# Cannot find where Excel Add-In is coming from. Want to remove it

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am a professional Excel Developer and I have an Add-In showing up when I open Excel, but cannot figure out how to remove it.  I have tried using the Excel Options>Add-In window and going to Excel Add-Ins, COMs, and every other option available in the Manage section.   I cannot find the Add-In that is appearing in the Add-Ins tab up in the ribbon.

I believe I got this by opening a file from a potential client about a year or so ago. (The file has since been deleted.) But again, I don't recall intentionally installing anything and I'm baffled as to why I cannot find out where to get rid of it.  Also, while I'm an Excel Developer, I've never gone down the route of creating Excel Add-Ins, so this is nothing I created myself or attempted to work on for a client.

Any thoughts?  I'm running Excel 365 on Windows 10.  I'm really hoping not to have to uninstall and re-install MS Office.

Thank you.

Comment: Would help to have any info on the add-in in question prob

Comment: The Add-In simply has a drop down button on the Excel Ribbon.  There are 3 choices.  Every time I click one, it says it cannot find a file (refers to a ".xlsm" file I once had on my Desktop).  That's about really all I can add.  I don't recall ever using the Add-In and even so, the file is gone  I should be able to remove the Add-In, correct?

Comment: Does `ActiveMenuBar.Reset` in the Immediate Window do anything?

Comment: Yes, that seems to have done it.  Thank you BigBen!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of closing this question:

Try `ActiveMenuBar.Reset` in the Immediate Window in the VBEditor to reset the ribbon.